# Configure MX to both SendGrid and Google Apps in order to use sendgrid parse API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, mx-record

I use Google Apps for MX records.

So I have this email that I also use to send emails in Sendgrid:

```
support@mycompany.com
```

Now, I want to parse emails sent directly to this support email and enter in my app using Parse API.

The problem is that i'll have to set the MX records, but to make both Google Apps and sendgrid works, probably I'll have to create a subdomain like:

```
support@mail.mycompany.com
```

Right now, I have a very good reputation with the first email.

**Am I gonna lose everything If I have to create the subdomain and start parsing emails?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, reputation has a lot more to do with IP than domain (although with certain providers, domain certainly plays a part). So, switching your support emails to `support@mail.example.com` is not the end of the world.

However, if you want to prevent this, there are a couple solutions you can use:

- **`Reply-To`**, while still sending from `support@example.com` you could have a `Reply-To` of `support@mail.example.com` (or taken a step further, `$UNIQUE_TICKET_HASH@mail.example.com`). You'll see this is what Github and Zendesk do for their emails. *This is probably best.*
- **Forwarding**, you can setup your Google Apps account to forward every email from `support@example.com` to `support@mail.example.com`. However, this means you're counting on Google Apps to be up and running for your support emails to work. While this is probably a safe assumption it still *adds unnecessary complexity to your system.*

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! Why do you think they create a $UNIQUE_TICKET_HASH ?

Comment: It allows them to easily thread the the messages. Instead of trying to figure out what conversation it's a part of by guessing from your address and hints in the email, they can just do a lookup on the ID in the email you send.